# Why is HashMap size different than the number of lines in the file?

Tags: java, file, hashmap

Suppose I have a file that has for example data of the following kind:

```
 info1 word1
 info2 word2
 info3 word3
 info2 word4
```

etc

Now, I want to create a mapping function for the words in each line. So I initially read the line, split it using the space, and get the word.

Now this word will be the value. I know that all the words are different and unique. However the information may not be unique.

About the key, since I'm mostly interested in the information associated with each word, I just create a String for it that is essentially all the line.

I know that the information might not be different, but the lines definitely are, since the words are definitely different.

The file has 40000 lines, however the size of the HashMap is 38490.

I don't understand what's happening here. Is my logic wrong?

here is the code:

```
private static void loadInfo(HashMap<String, String> info, File File){
  try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String[] dataInLine = new String[2];
    String line = br.readLine();
    int counter = 0;
    while (line != null) {

      lineData = line.split("\\s+");
      info.put(lineData[1], line);
      line = br.readLine();
      counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter); //counter shows the correct amount of lines
    System.out.println(info.size()); //this shows less than the amount of lines
  } catch (IOException io) {
  }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the keys are unique?

Comment: Keys in HashMaps are unique, so if it you try to add another line with the same key, it will just overwrite the value at that position, so you have 40000 - 38490 duplicates. You should consider using some data structure as the value then you can just add to that.

Comment: Indeed the keys are not unique. I should have checked this better. Thanks everyone for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

This would happen if you have duplicate keys; `put` will overwrite the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood your list of words is actually not unique.  You could do a check before your call to `.put()` to determine whether a word already exists and report a duplicate:

```
while (line != null) {

      lineData = line.split("\\s+");
      final String word = lineData[1];
      final String previous = info.get(word);
      if (previous != null) { 
         System.err.println("Duplicate at count "+line+" of word "+word);
         System.err.println(" original line: "+previous);
         System.err.println("      new line: "+line);
      }
      info.put(word, line);
      line = br.readLine();
      counter++;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably *do* have some duplicate keys.

An easy way to check if you are replacing a previous value is to look at the return value of `put`:

```
String last = info.put(lineData[1], line);
if( last != null )
    System.err.println("Warning: replaced value for key "+lineData[1]+", last value was: "+last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have duplicate keys, e.g. "info2" in your example maps to "word2" and to "word4".

If you need to have keys that map to multiple values, you want a "multimap".  You can make your own using the type `HashMap<String, Set<String>>` (each key maps to a set of values).  Or use a pre-existing one such as the one from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html).

Using your own, each time you want to add a mapping you need to check whether the key exists; if not add it mapping to an empty set.  Then to add the mapping, put the value into that key's set.

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> info;
...
if (!info.contains(lineData[1])) {
    info.put(lineData[1], new HashSet<String>());
}
info.get(lineData[1]).put(line);
```